# Infinitary union

Tags: notation

I came across $$ x \in \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_i $$ and some other notations similar to this one. I wonder if i can use this notation, let's say for intervals, for example $$ x \in \bigcup\limits_{k \in \mathbb Z} \left[2k\pi-\frac{7\pi}{6},2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}\right]$$ is the set of solutions of $ \sin(x) \le \frac{1}{2} $.

Comment: Absolutely! This is even what is typically done.

Comment: Many books use this notation, so don't sweat over it

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses. That really helped me.